# Faster killing of ECS containers based on inactive tasks?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I've been lurking for years and the time has finally come to post my first question!
So, my GitLab/Terraform/AWS pipeline pushes containers to Fargate. Once the task definition gets updated, new containers go live and pass health checks. At this point both the old and the new containers are up:

[image]

It takes several minutes until the auto-scaler shuts down the old containers. This is in a dev environment so nobody is accessing anything and there are no connections to drain. Other than manually, is there a way to make this faster or even instant?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you found a solution by now?

Comment: @trallnag, not really. You can reduce the "deregistration delay", although that only affects how fast AWS marks the task version as "inactive". I've instead worked on reducing the time to spin up the container and created smaller health check intervals

Comment: Stuck with the same issue, tried different things. No positive results. Please let us know if you managed to work this out.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to reduce the time you have to wait for tasks to drain. Go to EC2 -> Target Groups -> (Select your target group) -> Description and scroll down. At the bottom is a property called "Deregistration Delay". This is the amount of time the target group will allow connections to drain before shutting down a container (I think it defaults to 5 minutes). Just reduce that value and you should be able to deploy much quicker. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but deregistering only marks the task definition as "inactive". My goal is to reduce the time it takes to kill containers AFTER they get marked as inactive.